# MVC3 Model property bound to Html.DropdownListfor not updated on selecting dropdown by Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, html.dropdownlistfor

I have a MVC3 application with ASPX view engine. My page is having a dropdownlist created by

```
Html.DropdownListFor(m=>m.EmpId,(selectlist)Model.EmpDetails).
```

I update this dropdown on a situation where it would have only one item and make that disabled, by Jquery. Now when I go to form post, my model's `'EmpId'` property is not updated with the corresponding value of its selected item in dropdown list. I suspect, since the dropdownlist is not manually selected (updated by Jquery), I'm not getting `'EmpId'` in my model. Is there a way to overcome this issue?

With regards,
Saravanan

Answer (score 0):

Disabled form fields are not posted to the server. you can make it readonly if u want to stop users from manually changing it

Comment: readonly attribute is not available for htmlhelper's dropdownlist. So I had to use Hidden fields and update it as required.

Answer (score 0):

`disabled` form fields do not participate in form values sent to server. That is why your EmpId is not populated on server - it does not exist there. Making that `readonly` instead of `disabled` may help you. Do not disable form field if you need it on server.